# "non-zero exit status" installing package from GitHub on Mac

Tags: r, macos

The package is eegUtils. I have been trying to install it according to the instructions on GitHub (https://github.com/craddm/eegUtils):

```
install.packages("remotes")
remotes::install_github("craddm/eegUtils")
```

but i keep getting a non-zero exit status. can anyone help? I am using Mac Os Big Sur, and my R is up to date.

This is my output:

```
Downloading GitHub repo craddm/eegUtils@HEAD
✔  checking for file ‘/private/var/folders/zg/f64kxkls63n395jmly1jbpc00000gn/T/RtmpzuglrR/remotes13c7c1e1d76f2/craddm-eegUtils-f65305a/DESCRIPTION’ ...
─  building ‘eegUtils_0.6.1.tar.gz’ation ...
   
* installing *source* package ‘eegUtils’ ...
** using staged installation
** libs
clang++ -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -std=gnu++11 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/Rcpp/include' -I'/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/RcppArmadillo/include' -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
In file included from RcppExports.cpp:4:
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/RcppArmadillo/include/RcppArmadillo.h:34:
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h:57:
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/DataFrame.h:136:18: warning: unused variable 'data' [-Wunused-variable]
            SEXP data = Parent::get__();
                 ^
1 warning generated.
clang++ -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -std=gnu++11 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/Rcpp/include' -I'/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/RcppArmadillo/include' -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c base_mat.cpp -o base_mat.o
In file included from base_mat.cpp:1:
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/RcppArmadillo/include/RcppArmadillo.h:34:
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h:57:
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/DataFrame.h:136:18: warning: unused variable 'data' [-Wunused-variable]
            SEXP data = Parent::get__();
                 ^
1 warning generated.
clang++ -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -std=gnu++11 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/Rcpp/include' -I'/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/RcppArmadillo/include' -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c ica_test.cpp -o ica_test.o
In file included from ica_test.cpp:1:
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/RcppArmadillo/include/RcppArmadillo.h:34:
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h:57:
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/DataFrame.h:136:18: warning: unused variable 'data' [-Wunused-variable]
            SEXP data = Parent::get__();
                 ^
1 warning generated.
clang++ -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -std=gnu++11 -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -L/usr/local/lib -o eegUtils.so RcppExports.o base_mat.o ica_test.o -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -lRlapack -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -lRblas -L/usr/local/gfortran/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin18/8.2.0 -L/usr/local/gfortran/lib -lgfortran -lquadmath -lm -F/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/.. -framework R -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/gfortran/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin18/8.2.0'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/gfortran/lib'
ld: library not found for -lgfortran
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [eegUtils.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘eegUtils’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/eegUtils’
Warning message:
In i.p(...) :
  installation of package ‘/var/folders/zg/f64kxkls63n395jmly1jbpc00000gn/T//RtmpzuglrR/file13c7c206c1950/eegUtils_0.6.1.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: It seems that gfortran is missing. See the following page: https://mac.r-project.org/tools/

Comment: thank you so so much!